# Updating SVN folders using SVN export

Tags: svn

I got an SVN repo of 14 G in size on trunk which is updated every now and then. My script runs an rsync after doing an svn export of the trunk to the linux filesystem to a different environment. The users now want this to be done every 5 minutes instead of the 1 hour update I was doing due to the size.
How do I only update the SVN exported files on the filesystem rather than exporting the whole repository each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `svn export`, use `svn checkout` to *export* the trunk to the file system, and reuse this directory, e.g. something like:

```bsh
while sleep 5m; do
    svn checkout https://svn.example.org/svn/foobar/trunk /srv/foobar
    rsync -az /srv/foobar ... # exclude .svn subdirectory
done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Thanks nosid.